# Invertible sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For a nonsingular curve $X$ and algebraically closed field $k$, let $K = k(X),$ we define a sheaf as for some open subset $U\subseteq X$, $L_{D}(U) $={ $f\in K : \nu_{p}(f) + n_{p}D \geq 0 $} for all $p\in U$ and $D$ is a divisor. Then $L_{D}$ is a sheaf which is invertible. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hint: For any $P$, pick a uniformizer $z_P$ at $P$, and a small enough neighborhood $U_P$ around $P$ so that $z_P$ is holomorphic on $U_P$. What does $L_D|{U_P}$ look like?

Comment: There are a few typos. I think $K=k(X)$. Is $D$ a fixed divisor? Also, I'm not sure what $L_D(U)$ should equal, but what is written doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Do you mean $L_D(U) = \{ f \in K : \nu_p(f) = n_p(D) \;\text{for all $p \in U$} \}$?

Comment: I think it should be $L_D(U)=\{v_p(f)+n_pD \geq 0 \text{ for all } p \in U\}$. Also, as Matt says, you need to be clear about what $D$ is.

Comment: Thank you all. It seems $L_{D}(U)$ is an $\mathbb O_{X}(U)$-module.

Comment: @Sanchez If $X = \Bbb{C}$ then we can write $f = (x - a_1)\ldots (x - a_n)/(x - b_1) \ldots (x- b_m)$. Then isn't $L_D \cong \frac{(x-b_1)\ldots (x-b_m)}{ (x-a_1)\ldots (x-a_n)}\mathcal{O}_X$?

Comment: I'm sorry to do this again, but I'm still confused. What is $n_p$? It seems to change as $p$ changes? I can't think of any intrinsic integer attached to every point of $X$ and it can't be coming from $D$ or $f$. Also, now we have $\nu_p(f)$ (a number?) plus a divisor is greater than or equal to $0$. I'm still not sure if this is what is meant.

Comment: Thank you all. @ Matt here $n_{p}$ is a coefficient of $P$ at $D,$ which is a integer.

Comment: Oh. I see. I would write $\nu_p(f)+n_p\geq 0$ or something. The notation $n_pD$ has a standard meaning and it isn't comparable to $\nu_p(f)$.